# I got error while inserting temporary address and permanent address to student by composition relation ship in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
**This is student pojo class**

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int studentId;
    private String StudentName;
    @Embedded
    private Adress add;
    @Embedded
    private Adress temp;
    public void setTemp(Adress temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }
    public void setAdd(Adress add) {
        this.add = add;
    }
   public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        StudentName = studentName;
    }}

** this is Address pojo class**
@Embeddable
public class Adress {

    @Column(name="village" )
    private String village;
    @Column(name="pin")
    private int pin;
    public void setVillage(String village) {
        this.village = village;
    }

    public void setPin(int pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }}

** Main class **

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory factory=Sessionfactory.getfactory();

        Session session=factory.openSession();
        Adress a=new Adress();
        a.setPin(123);
        a.setVillage("kanipakam");

        Adress a2=new Adress();

        a2.setVillage("kanchi");
        a2.setPin(1234);

        Student s=new Student();

        s.setAdd(a);
        s.setTemp(a2);


        s.setStudentId(101);
        s.setStudentName("uday");
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(s);

        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("object saved");
        session.close();
        factory.close();
        }}
** showing error**
```

**while running this code its show below error please help me**
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.sathya.pojo.Student column: pin (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:709)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:731)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:727)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:753)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:506)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
        at com.sathya.singleton.Sessionfactory.getfactory(Sessionfactory.java:21)
        at com.sathya.Test.Test.main(Test.java:16)

Answer (score 0):

`@Embedded` annotation specifies that fields from the object are persisted in the same table as root entity. The names for the columns are taken from the `@Embeddable` configuration. So in your case

```
@Embedded
private Adress add;
@Embedded
private Adress temp;
```

Specifies that there are 2 objects of type `Adress` on your `@Entity`. The problem is that gived your current configuration `add.village` and `temp.village` both will be mapped to `village` column of `student` table.

You have 2 options to resolve the issue:

1. Override mappings for one (or both) `@Embedded` properties and specify different columns like described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embedded.html)
2. Use `many-to-one` or `one-to-one` relation to address and store address records in a separate database table.